# Absolute convergence detail

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am currently studying series and I have a question which is more of a detail...Let’s say that I have the following series: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n 100}{2n+3}$$
and I want to check for absolute convergence, studying this series, $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left|\frac{(-1)^n 100}{2n+3}\right|$$
now, when i perform a test, can I drop immediately the absolute value (we know that the sequence is going to be always positive so we can immediately rewrite it as $\frac{100}{2n + 3}$ or i need to do one more step?Thank you for your time

Comment: No, no other step is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. $\left|\frac{(-1)^n 100}{2n+3}\right| = \frac{100}{2n+3}$
, so $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \left|\frac{(-1)^n 100}{2n+3}\right|$ and $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{100}{2n+3}$ are just the same series, term-by-term.

In general, if $a_n = b_n$, you can freely replace $a_n$ with $b_n$ in any expression.

Comment: Thank you very much @mihaild

Answer (score 2):

As already noticed, no further step is strictly needed but we could add one more step as follows

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left|\frac{(-1)^n 100}{2n+3}\right|= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left|(-1)^n\right| 100}{2n+3}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{100}{2n+3}$$

to emphasize we are acting on the alternating term.